Numerically solving frame-dragging equation in Hartle-Thorne formalism
I'm trying to write a Python code to implement Hartle-Thorne approximation formalism for rotating neutron stars. In this formalism, I am required to solve the following second order differential equation:
$$ \frac{1}{r^4}\frac{d}{dr}(r^4 \frac{d \bar{\omega(r)}}{dr}) + \frac{4}{r}\frac{dj(r)}{dr}\bar{\omega(r)} = 0$$ with the boundary conditions $\bar{\omega}(r=0) = \bar{\omega_c}$ and $\frac{d\bar{\omega}}{dr}|_{r=0} = 0$ where $\bar{\omega_c}$ is an arbitrary constant.  $j$ is defined as $j = e^{-\nu(r)}\sqrt{1-\frac{2m(r)}{r}}$ inside the star and $j(r)=1$ for $r \geq R$ where $R$ is the radius of the star . $\nu$ is the metric function defined as
$$\frac{d\nu}{dr} = -2(\epsilon + p)^{-1}\frac{dp}{dr}$$ I obtained the metric by simultaneously solving it's differential equation with the TOV equations using a RK4 solver. Now I am trying to solve that second order differential equation using odeint but the result does not seem to be correct. The issues are as follows:

The results I obtained does not match with the results published in the related paper.
The results change if I change the boundary condition on $\bar{\omega}$ even though this boundary condition is supposed to be arbitrary.

I need some help to identify the correct approach to solve this equation: can I solve it separately now that I already have obtained all the necessary quantities from the TOV-RK4 run (that's what I am doing), or do I need to solve it with the TOV equations themselves? For those who might need it, here is the paper that describes the formalism and all the necessary equations.

It will work if you use Java instead of Python. The math works out differently if you use Java code instead of Python code.

I don't know for sure, but I imagine $\omega(r)$ needs to be solved in conjunction with the pressure and mass equations

It is a bit hard to pinpoint the problem from the description given but here are some comments:

It is possible to solve the TOV equations and frame-dagging equation in sequence, if one stores the TOV solutions for $M(r)$, $P(r)$, and $\rho(r)$ (or $j(r)$ if one really wants to use that -- later more on this) in form of some interpolating functions such that a solver for the frame-dragging equation can access them. But it is simpler to just solve the equations together I suppose.

I would recommend solving the second-order ODE for $\bar{\omega}(r)$ by the standard method of using its derivative  $\bar{\omega}'(r)$ as an auxillary variable. Leading to a system
$$
\begin{align}
\bar{\omega}''(r) &= \bar{\omega}'(r)\, ,\tag{1.1}\\
\bar{\omega}'(r) &=\frac{4 \left(2 M(r)-r+\pi  r^3 (P(r)+\rho(r))\right)}{r (r-2 M(r))} \bar{\omega}'(r) +\frac{16 \pi  r (P(r)+\rho (r))}{r-2 M(r)}\bar{\omega}(r)\,.\tag{1.2}
\end{align}
$$
Now the question arises what initial and boundary conditions to use to solve those for a given TOV background star. I like to work with the enclosed mass $M(r)$, pressure gradient $P(r)$, and energy density gradient $\rho(r)$, instead of $j(r)$.

We first may notice, that the equations are homogeneous and invariant under rescaling but $\bar{\omega}(r)$ still has a specific shape around $r=0$:
$$
\begin{align}
\bar{\omega}(r) &= \bar{\omega}_0 \left(1 + \frac{8}{5} \pi r^2 (P(0)+\rho(0))+O(r^4)\right)\, ,\tag{2.1}\\
\bar{\omega}'(r) &= \bar{\omega}_0 \left(\frac{16}{5} \pi r (P(0)+\rho(0))+O(r^3)\right)\, ,\tag{2.2}
\end{align}
$$
with the arbitrary scale $\bar{\omega}_0>0$ and the central pressure $P(0)$ and corresponding central energy density $\rho(0)$ of the background TOV star. Using this relation one can construct a proper initial condition for the frame-dragging equations at a small non-zero $r_0$ and integrate them from $r_0$ to the surface of the star $R$.

The boundary conditions for the frame-dragging equation are by no means arbitrary since they in fact include/determine the moment of inertia/angular momentum of the star. In fact the values of $\bar{\omega}(R)$ and $\bar{\omega}'(R)$ on the stellar surface are
$$
\begin{align}
\bar{\omega}'(R) &= \frac{\Omega}{c} \frac{6I}{R^4}\, ,\tag{3.1}\\
\bar{\omega}(R) &=\frac{\Omega}{c} \left(1-\frac{2I}{R^3}\right)\,,\tag{3.2}
\end{align}
$$
since the exterior solution is given by
$$
\bar{\omega}_>(r)= \Omega\left(1-\frac{2 I}{r^3}\right)\, ,\tag{4}
$$
with the angular velocity $\Omega$ and the moment of inertia $I$. For a given $\Omega$ and a solution $\{\bar{\omega}(R),\bar{\omega}'(R)\}$ computed with a specific $\bar{\omega}_0 $ one may solve the equation system (3) to determine the constant $c$ and the moment of inertia $I$. With the constant $c$ at hand one should rescale the numerical interior solution for $\bar{\omega}(r)$ with $c$ to obtain an interior solution which matches Eq. (4).

Depending on the definition $\bar{\omega}(r)$ might include $\Omega$ or its scaled out, since the whole $O(\Omega^1)$-Hartle-Thorne formalism is of course by construction linear in $\Omega$ and the fundamental quantity to compute here is the moment of inertia $I$ of a slowly rotating star. The angular momentum follows trivially in $O(\Omega^1)$ as $J=\Omega I$ as usual.


So I think the issue of OP probably lies in improper initial and/or boundary conditions. Equations (2) and (3) and the matching to Eq. (4) -- the determination of $c$ and $I$ -- are crucial here to get a smooth physical solution for $\bar{\omega}(r)$. I hope this helps to narrow down the problem.
One last suggestion: troubleshoot your code with a simple EoS. A good candidate is the (unphysical) constant density EoS (interior Schwarzschild solution): $\rho(P)=\rho_0 = \frac{3 M}{4\pi R^3}$ for which a corresponding central pressure of $P_0=\rho_0 \frac{3Z+\sqrt{1-2Z}-1}{4-9Z}$ with $Z=M/R$ should yield a nice star with the consistent radius $R$ and mass $M$. For such a star the moment of inertia should be
$$
I = \frac{2 Z R^3}{5}\left( 1+ \frac{6}{7}Z+\frac{106}{105}Z^2+O(Z^3)\right)\,.
$$
So choosing one with a low compactness $Z=M/R$ one should approach the classical value $I = \frac{2}{5}  M R^2$. For $Z=0.15$, $M=1.214 M_\odot$, and $R=11.952\,\mathrm{km}$ an old numerical computation of mine yielded $I/(M R^2)=0.461$.
